# Hide, Show and Move Cursor in a Xamarin.Forms PCL Project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am prototyping an application for my employer using Xamarin.Forms PCL. One of the requirements is that during certain points within the application, the cursor must be hidden, shown, and then moved from one location to another. The moving of the cursor should be smooth, starting of slow, then speeding up, and slowing down as it reaches the required location.

Although I have accomplished this once in WPF, I have searched the web and Xamarin documentation, and have not been able to find out how to do this in Xamarin.Forms.

The nearest I have found on the Xamarin website is the Cursor class in the System.Windows.Forms.dll, but this does not seem to be available to Xamarin.Forms.

Would I need to use custom renderers for Android, iOS, and UWP, and if so what are the required references for each?

Please provide some resources that I can refer to, to accomplish my tasks, and if you have any some source code to get me started.

Comment: mobile devices don't generally have the concept of a "cursor" because the UI focus is wherever your finger is touching

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have to target devices with mice and without mice on Windows, Android, iOS and macOS.

Comment: I suppose that I can simply write the program. Then video the process a user needs to carry with a mouse on desktop computers and laptops, and do the same for people using touch devices.

Comment: I have accepted Jason's advice and require no further answers.